# Find $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{x_n}{\sqrt{n}}$ where $x_{n+1}=x_n+\frac{n}{x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, recurrence-relations

Assume a positive sequence $\{x_n\} $ satisfies $$x_{n+1}=x_n+\frac{n}{x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n}.$$ Find $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\dfrac{x_n}{\sqrt{n}}$.

Assume the limit we want is $L$. Then by Stolz theorem, one can obtain
\begin{align*}
L&=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{x_n}{\sqrt{n}}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{x_{n+1}-x_n}{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{2n\sqrt{n}}{x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n}\\
&=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{2n\sqrt{n}-2(n-1)\sqrt{n-1}}{x_n}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{3\sqrt{n}}{x_n}=\frac{3}{L},
\end{align*}
which implies $L=\sqrt{3}$. But how to prove the limit exists?

Comment: Just mentioning that your second application of the Stolz-Cesàro theorem requires that $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_n \to \infty$ (which is easy so show).

Comment: yes. but the whole solution depends on the existence of the present limit. how to show this?@M

Comment: Let us set $S_n=x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_n$, such that $x_{n+1}=S_{n+1}-S_n$, $x_n=S_n-S_{n-1}$ and 
$$ S_{n+1} - 2 S_n + S_{n-1} = \frac{n}{S_n}. \tag{1}$$
We may notice that a solution of the differential equation $f''(x)=\frac{x}{f(x)}$ is given by $\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} x^{3/2}$, and $(1)$ is a discretization of this differential equation.

Comment: If we manage to adapt the technique for the continuous case to the discrete case, the existence of the limit of $S_n/n^{3/2}$ should follow.

Comment: I was wrong, I believed that the constants involved in the upper/lower bounds were linked by a relation of the form $K\to \frac{K^2+3}{2K}$, converging to $\sqrt{3}$. If we just have $K\to 3/K$ we cannot deduce much.

Comment: This is a special case of the Open Problem 1.30 in [this book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-030-77139-3).

Comment: @GabrielRomon : Do you know if this problem has applications or research meaning?

Comment: also asked at https://mathoverflow.net/q/426341/11260

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a community-wiki answer illustrating **Iosif Pinelis**'s solution (with some simplifications).

- If you like this, please give kudos to [his original solution](https://mathoverflow.net/a/426410/15602) as well.
- Also, feel free to improve this answer as you please!

---

**Setting.** We will write $s_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} x_k$, so that the recurrence relation takes the form

$$ x_{n+1} = x_n + \frac{n}{s_n}. \tag{RE} $$

Also, let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ by

$$ \alpha = \liminf_{n\to\infty} \frac{x_n}{\sqrt{n}}
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
\beta = \limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{x_n}{\sqrt{n}}. $$

Our goal is to prove that $\alpha = \beta = \sqrt{3}$. To make use of these quantities, we will frequently utilize the following inequalities:

> **Lemma.** Let $(a_n)$ be any sequence of real numbers, and let $p > 0$. Then
> $$ \color{navy}{\liminf_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n}{n^p}}
> \geq \liminf_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n - a_{n-1}}{pn^{p-1}} \tag{SC1} $$
> and
> $$ \color{navy}{\limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n}{n^p}}
> \leq \limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n - a_{n-1}}{pn^{p-1}}. \tag{SC2} $$
>
> *Proof.* This is an immediate consequence of the [Stolz–Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem#The_general_form) together with the asymptotic formula $n^p - (n-1)^p \sim pn^{p-1}$.

**Step 1.** Since $(x_n)$ is increasing, we know that $s_n \leq n x_n$. Then by the lemma,

\begin{align*}
\alpha^2
= \liminf_{n\to\infty} \frac{x_n^2}{n}
&\geq \liminf_{n\to\infty} \left( x_{n+1}^2 - x_n^2 \right)
\tag*{by $\color{#2E8B57}{\text{(SC1)}}$} \\
&\geq \liminf_{n\to\infty} \frac{2nx_n}{s_n}
\tag*{by $\color{#2E8B57}{\text{(RE)}}$} \\
&\geq 2.
\tag*{$\because \ s_n \leq n x_n$}
\end{align*}

Now, by the Stolz–Cesàro theorem again,

\begin{align*}
\beta
= \limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{x_n}{\sqrt{n}}
&\leq \limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{x_{n+1} - x_n}{\frac{1}{2}n^{-1/2}}
\tag*{by $\color{#2E8B57}{\text{(SC2)}}$} \\
&= \limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{2n^{3/2}}{s_n}
\tag*{by $\color{#2E8B57}{\text{(RE)}}$} \\
&= \left[ \liminf_{n\to\infty} \frac{s_n}{2n^{3/2}} \right]^{-1} \tag{1} \\
&\leq \left[ \liminf_{n\to\infty} \frac{x_n}{3\sqrt{n}} \right]^{-1}
= \frac{3}{\alpha}.
\tag*{by $\color{#2E8B57}{\text{(SC1)}}$}
\end{align*}

These altogether show that $0 < \alpha \leq \beta < \infty$.

(*Remark.* Starting from $\alpha$ and applying a similar argument as above, we can show that $\alpha \beta = 3$. However, this does not determine the value of $\alpha$ and $\beta$. So, we will not bother to prove this.)

**Step 2.** Using the recurrence relation $\color{#2E8B57}{\text{(RE)}}$, we find that

\begin{align*}
s_{n+1}^2 - 2s_n^2 + s_{n-1}^2
&= (s_n + x_{n+1})^2 - 2s_n^2 + (s_n - x_n)^2 \\
&= 2 s_n(x_{n+1} - x_n) + x_{n+1}^2 + x_n^2 \\
&= 2n + x_{n+1}^2 + x_n^2. \tag{2}
\end{align*}

Using this, we get

\begin{align*}
\liminf_{n\to\infty} \frac{s_n^2}{n^3}
&\geq \liminf_{n\to\infty} \frac{s_{n+1}^2 - s_n^2}{3n^2}
\tag*{by $\color{#2E8B57}{\text{(SC1)}}$} \\
&\geq \liminf_{n\to\infty} \frac{s_{n+1}^2 - 2s_n^2 + s_{n+1}^2}{6n}
\tag*{by $\color{#2E8B57}{\text{(SC1)}}$} \\
&\geq \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{6} \biggl( \liminf_{n\to\infty} \frac{x_{n+1}^2}{n} \biggr) + \frac{1}{6} \biggl( \liminf_{n\to\infty} \frac{x_n^2}{n} \biggr)
\tag*{by $\color{#2E8B57}{\text{(2)}}$} \\
&= \frac{1 + \alpha^2}{3}.
\end{align*}

Plugging this into $\color{#2E8B57}{\text{(1)}}$,

\begin{align*}
\beta
\leq \left[ \liminf_{n\to\infty} \frac{s_n}{2n^{3/2}} \right]^{-1}
\leq 2\sqrt{\frac{3}{1+\alpha^2}}. \tag{3}
\end{align*}

A similar calculation also shows that

$$ \alpha \geq 2\sqrt{\frac{3}{1+\beta^2}}. \tag{4} $$

**Step 3.** Define $f(x) = 2\sqrt{\frac{3}{1+x^2}}$, and note that $f$ is decreasing on $[0, \infty)$. So, using $\color{#2E8B57}{\text{(3)}}$ and $\color{#2E8B57}{\text{(4)}}$, we get

$$ \beta \leq f(\alpha) \implies f(f(\alpha)) \leq f(\beta)
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
\alpha \geq f(\beta) \implies f(\alpha) \leq f(f(\beta)) $$

and hence

$$ \beta \leq f(f(\beta)) \qquad\text{and}\qquad f(f(\alpha)) \leq \alpha. $$

It is not hard to check that these inequalities yield $\beta \leq \sqrt{3} \leq \alpha$:

[image: graphs]

So, using the obvious relation $\alpha \leq \beta$, we conclude that

$$ \sqrt{3} \leq \alpha \leq \beta \leq \sqrt{3} $$

and therefore $\alpha = \beta = \sqrt{3}$.